# Homotopy (co)limit of sets

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

There are general constructions for homotopy (co)limit of diagrams in spaces 
$$D:I \rightarrow Top$$

> I was wondering if the homotopy (co)limit of *discrete diagrams*, i.e. when the spaces are all discrete,  coincides with (co)limit.

A little update to my question: (in response to Connor)

(i) What kind of diagrams $I$ would be imply they conincide?

(ii) What general theory may I use?

(iii) I am actuallly interested of diagrams indexed by simplex category, $\Delta$.

---

I have come to an example of interest.

The Segal condition for *spaces* and *sets*.

> **Definition of Segal Space:** Let $X_*$ be a simplicial space: the composition of the maps for $n \ge 2$
>   $$ X_n \rightarrow X_1 \times _{X_0} \cdots \times_{X_0} X_1 \rightarrow X_1 \times^h_{X_0} \cdots \times ^h _{X_0} X_1 $$
>   is a *weak equivalence*.  The last limit is a homotopy limit.
>
> **Definition of Segal Set:** Same as above but we require
>   $$ X_n \rightarrow X_1 \times _{X_0} \cdots \times_{X_0} X_1 $$
>   is a *set bijection*.

**Question:** Now suppose we equip each space $X_n$ with discrete topology. $X_*$ a simplicial space equivalent to $X_*$ a simplicial set?

Comment: Somewhat relevant to (iii) is https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+limit#OverSimplicialDiagrams. It is for particularly simple diagrams indexed by $\Delta ^{op}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, what are your thoughts on the example I gave?

Comment: Homotopy pullbacks where everything is discrete should just be the regular pullback. So if you have a Segal space where the spaces are discrete it should be what you call a Segal set. Now Segal sets are very different from simplicial sets because I don’t think simplicial sets usually have this pullback condition.

Comment: I misread your question. Yes simplicial spaces with discrete spaces are the same as simplicial set, so Segal sets are the same as discrete Segal spaces.

Comment: How so? I mean to prove this we need to show weak equivalence between normal limit and homotopy limit.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, as I haven't read about this for some while: a) we can always assign diagram categories Top^D with projective model structure.  b)The diagrams with discrete spaces are fibrant objects. c) To compute homotopy limit is thus same as limit. (fibrant replacement + apply limit functor).

Answer (score 3):

No, the homotopy pushout of $* \leftarrow S^0 \rightarrow *$ is $S^1$ but the pushout as sets is $*$.

If all the maps are injective, then for finite diagrams colimits should agree since all the maps are cofibrations.

Comment: Thansk a lot Connor. Few more questions (i) What would be the analogous conditionsfor limits? (ii) what general theory is applied here?

Comment: @BryanShih I don't really know much about computing homotopy (co)limits so I can't give a good answer. One thing you should be way of is that an inverse limit of sets as a topological space space will have a profinite topology, but when you consider this in the homotopy category it is equivalent to a discrete space.

Comment: @BryanShih Generally the process to compute homotopy (co)limits is to replace some of your maps with (co)fibrations I'm a little hazy on how this would work for limits of spaces where the map is not surjective on path components (in your case simply non surjective maps).